# JS: With factory functions, do you have to set your arguments like in classes?

Tags: javascript

With factory functions, can you just use the arguments anywhere or do you have to set them first as you do with classes?

```
  function Car(name, engineSize) {

     // do you need to do:  this.name = name;  this.engineSize = 
     // engineSize

     return {

        carIdentification() {

            return "I am a " + name
        }

      }
   }
```

Comment: Because you're explicitly returning an object, don't assign to `this`, instead assign to the object you're returning (or just use the closure if you don't want the info to be visible outside)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `this`, because `this` has meaning when the function is called as a *constructor function* (i.e. with `new`) or using `Function#call`, `Function#apply`...

Use arguments *as is*.

OP question: *What if I want the car, by itself, to have a name attached to it?*

Then one would attach it to the returned object:

```
function Car(name, engineSize) {
  return {
    name,
    carIdentification() {
      return "I am a " + name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks . What if I want the car, by itself, to have a name attached to it?

Comment: @JohnNada No problem. Just add `name` as a property of the returned object.

Comment: hmm, not sure what you mean by that

Comment: @JohnNada See my edited answer, I've answered your question

Comment: yep, all good -- I'll vote your answers as the accepted answer once the time limit passes in a few minutes!  thanks again

Comment: @JohnNada You're welcome! I'm glad I could address your concern :-)